# After upgrade Ubuntu display 2 software center and filezilla not working

Tags: upgrade, software-center

updating Ubuntu  15.10 to 16.04 display **2 software center icon**
and that both software center is working

**1. Ubuntu software center  (15.10)**

**2. software center  (16.04)**

**3. filezilla not working after upgrade ubuntu**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try deleting the config file `sudo rm ~/.config/filezilla/filezilla.xml` since it seems there is a problem with the old configuration

Then remove old software centre `sudo apt-get remove software-centre` since ubuntu 16.04 uses `gnome-software` centre.

Comment: thank you it working...  and  **display 2 software center**

Comment: just remove the old one by `sudo apt-get remove software-centre`

Comment: which one is remove 15.10 or 16.04

Comment: 15.10,,the latest one as a different name

Comment: 16.04 name is  software center

Comment: no its replaced with `gnome-software` centrer,the name is that but the package name is different now